# ¿Se puede guardar la salida de passwd en una variable y al mismo tiempo utilizarla con expect?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Necesito probar que cuando se crea un usuario y se va a proceder a crear su contraseña, dicha contraseña sigue una serie de normas (complejidad, longitud...).

Para ello estoy utilizando el siguiente comando en un script:

```
user="test"    
OUTPUT="$( sudo passwd "$user" 2>&1 > /dev/null)"
```

Así puedo recoger la salida stderr en OUTPUT.

El problema es que el script expect está esperando "Nueva contraseña:" para introducir una contraseña cualquiera.

El comando passwd muestra "Nueva contraseña:" también por la salida stderr que al estar redirigida no se muestra por pantalla y expect no continúa.

¿Alguna sugerencia para poder hacer ambas cosas al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Tiene que existir algo que no has mostrado en tu pregunta que te impide hacer `echo "Nueva contraseña:${OUTPUT}"`, ¿ verdad ?

Comment: En teoría no necesito hacer echo "Nueva contraseña:" si es a lo que te refieres. De hecho, después de hacer sudo passwd.... el script se queda esperando a que alguien introduzca datos, un echo a continuación solo saldría después de alguien introdujese contraseña. No sé si estoy aclarando tu pregunta

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no mucho :-) Creo entender que ... ¿ Tu problema se reduce a como introducir una nueva contraseña sin usar la consola ?

Comment: Correcto, y recoger los mensajes de error del comando passwd

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la aclaración que hizo @juanjo en los comentarios, te puedo sugerir que utilices el comando `chpass` para pasarle la contraseña:

```
$ sudo chpass <<< "<usuario>:<contraseña>"
```

Claramente esto **no es ideal**, **es muy peligroso**, porque quien tenga control del script (y no sólamente el que lo desarrolló) o los registros vistos por `ps`, `htop`, etc, tiene capacidad de ver lo que le suceda a estos datos.

Pero de todas maneras no soy policía, así tu script podría quedar así:

```
#!/bin/bash

validador() {
: << __doc
    Valida lo que quieras
__doc

    pass="$1"
    
    [ ${#pass} -le 4 ] && { echo "Demasiado corta" && exit 1; }
    [[ "$pass" =~ [0-9] ]] || { echo "Le faltan números" && exit 1 ;}
    
}

read -p "Ingrese usuario: " usuario
read -sp "Ingrese contraseña: " pass
echo

validador "$pass"

chpasswd <<< "$usuario:$pass"
```

Este script lo puedes correr con:

```
$ sudo ./script
Ingrese usuario: <el usuario que escribiste>
Ingrese contraseña: <La contraseña no se mostrará>
(en caso de error: ) Le faltan números
```

Con `chpasswd`, puedes almacenar el error en una variable como lo estabas haciendo:

```
$ log=$(echo "<usuario>:<contrasena>" | sudo chpasswd 2>&1);
```

Comment: La intención de mi script es probar que las reglas de contraseña del sistema operativo funcionan. Si en el script defino las propias reglas no estoy probando lo que quiero probar. De todas formas, conocer la utilidad del comando chpasswd me ha valido para conocer una vulnerabilidad en el sistema. Sigo buscando la forma...si es que la hay...

Comment: Vaya, en ese caso, tu pregunta principal cambia. Puedes poner esa pregunta en una publicación nueva; algo como "¿Cómo valida la contraseña useradd?" y lo que haz investigado. Si te animas a eso, te puedo sugerir que revises el archivo `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

Comment: Lo único que trate de responder con mi publicación, más que la validación, fue que puedes evitar el uso de `passwd` y su forma interactiva. Luego puedes guardar los errores en una variable. Justo como pensé que querías.

Comment: Gracias @Cuauhtli. De hecho tu propuesta de intentar no interactuar me ha hecho darle un giro a mi propuesta y encontrar una solución válida a mi problema. Dejaré la solución aquí y abriré un nuevo post como comentas

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he podido lograr lo que buscaba. Lo que necesitaba era interactuar con el comando passwd sin perder su salida stderr. Para ello he utilizado lo siguiente:

```
user="test"   
group="operator"
password="hola"

#Creando el usuario test

sudo useradd -m -g "$group" "$user"

#Comprueba que el usuario se ha creado en /etc/passwd
checkadd="$(sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep "$user" | cut -d ":" -f1)"

#Le pasa al comando passwd la variable password y almacena en OUTPUT las salidas stderr y stdout
OUTPUT="$(echo -e "$password" | sudo passwd "$user" 2>&1 )"

#Busca en OUTPUT la palabra "INCORRECTA"
error="$( echo "$OUTPUT" | grep INCORRECTA )"

echo "$error"
```

Así consigo que ni el usuario ni un script expect tenga que interactuar con este script y el resultado que obtengo es verificar que efectivamente las reglas de contraseña del sistema funcionan.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que eso funcione tal cual, debido a que `passwd` requiere de la confirmación. Por otro lado, el uso que le das a `echo -e` puede prescindir del parámetro ya que no utilizas caracteres especiales.

Comment: Me parece que lo que deberías hacer sería: `OUTPUT="$(echo -e "$password\n$password" | sudo passwd "$user" 2>&1 )"`. Es decir, volver a escribir esta contrasena pero separpandola con un salto de línea.

Comment: Como bien comentas el parámetro -e no es necesario. Por otro lado,  "$password\n$password" lo está cogiendo como si fuese una única cadena. Incialmente había probado con eso a sabiendas de la confirmación pero por alguna razón que aún desconozco basta con ponerlo una vez.

Comment: Se oye muy sospechoso eso. Si yo me encontrara con un funcionamiento anormal de mi `passwd`, dudaría de mi comando `passwd`, formatearía mi computadora, cambiaría mi contraseña y le preguntaría a mis compañeros que quién fue el gracioso que se metió con mis cosas.